# EXC_BAD_ACCESS in UISplitViewController after unwind segue, then returning

Tags: ios, swift, crash, uisplitviewcontroller

This is an application who interface consists of a tab controller (which has the rest of the interfaces residing in tabs), then two `UISplitViewControllers` with tables in them, and lastly a simple `UIView` with a button that allows the user to logout. The logout is implemented with an unwind segue back to the initial view controller (which is a login screen), and setting the root view controller of the app to a freshly instantiated version of the initial view controller (the login interface). After using this logout, then logging back in, the application immediately crashes with an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` exception.

I have tried multiple different ways of implementing the behavior of the logout button (to segue back to the login screen) but every attempt has failed with the same results.

By following the stack trace, I was able to determine that the crash is occurring in the `setCollapsedState` method of the `UISplitViewController`. This is not a custom implementation of a split view controller, just the default one.

In case this is relevant, I am setting one of the child view controllers of the parent view controller as the delegate, however when I tried changing this and not setting the delegate, nothing improved.

I am not sure what other information I can provide, other than this code snippet of the logout button. If there's any other information that I can supply, please let me know and I will post edits.

```
@IBAction func signoutButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    appDelegate.signOut()
    var rootVC = appDelegate.window?.rootViewController
    rootVC?.removeFromParentViewController()
    rootVC = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateInitialViewController()
    appDelegate.window!.rootViewController = rootVC
}
```